# Outputting None instead of Values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to utilize list comprehension to populate a new list, which is the length of text in a DataFrame column.

So if the text is "electrical engineer", it should output 19 etc. Instead, it just fills the list with None values

I have written out list comprehension below

```
all_text_length = [all_text_length.append(len(i)) for i in data['all_text']]
```

Expecting output of integer but its None

As a workaround, I am currently using (successfully)

````
[all_text_length.append(len(i)) for i in data['all_text']]```
````

Comment: `all_text_length = [len(i) for i in data['all_text']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation on `append`: it works in-place.  There is no returned value.  What you've written is essentially

```
all_text_length = [None for i in data['all_text']]
```

It appears that you're trying to make a list comprehension to entirely change your list.  Try this:

```
all_text_length = [len(i) for i in data['all_text']]
```

---

If you just need the lengths in a convenient form, would it do to form a new column?  Simply apply `len` to the df column.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append to the same list on which you are doing list comprehension. Since the append returns a None type, you are getting None. The below code should work,

```
all_text_length = map(len, data['all_text'])
```

`map` is a function that takes another function (first argument) and applies it to every element in an iterable (second argument) and returns a list of the results.

Answer (score 1):

The value  before the "for" statement in the list comprehension, will be added to the list. If you place a statement in there, like

> *all_text_length.append(len(i)*

, the **return** value of that function will be added. Because *.append()* doesnt have a**return**-statement in it, you get the value None as **return** type, wich will be added to your list.

Use the code @Prune recommended and it should work as you want.